# get Live Navigation advices Skmaps iOS

Tags: ios, skmaps

I am creating an application which is using skobbler iOS sdk. I am implementing the Navigation functionality between source and destination. When the route is calculated I get the whole advice information for that route through AdviceList in the delegate method

```
- (void)routingService:(SKRoutingService *)routingService didFinishRouteCalculationWithInfo:(SKRouteInformation*)routeInformation
```

Whereas I also want to get the Live Navigation information like if needs to turn left/turn right or this sort of information while navigating on a route. I could not find a function which provides this. There are delegate functions which provide formatted distance, estimated time, speed information, next and second next street information but i want to get the textual information what is provided by the advisory images. Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the 2.3 version, the live guidance information provided by the SKNavigationDelegate only contains raw information, as you mentioned. We are currently working on the full textual instructions, this will come in the 2.4. version of the SDK, along with text-to-speech audio guidance.

Answer (score 0):

`SKNavigationManager` and the respective Delegate, `SKNavigationDelegate` may helps you to get advisory images and relevant textual information.